# ANTLR: detect an optional token in front of a sequence of any characters

Tags: antlr

The goal is to match URLs (without the protocol) which may or may not include an optional hostname. For example

- amce.com/a/path
- /another/path/expr
- a/path/not/starting_with/slash

All 3 should match but ideally the grammar would allow recovering the hostname - acme.com - in the first expression.

So the parser grammar would ideally look like:

```
url: hostname? pathExpr
```

The problem is coming up with the Lexer Grammar

For instance

```
fragment ALPHANUM: [a-zA-Z0-9-];
fragment NAME: ALPHANUM+;

HOSTNAME: NAME ( '.' NAME)+ -> mode (PATH_MODE);

mode PATH_MODE;
PATH_EXPR: .+;
```

works fine for the first case but will not match the other 2.

How do I do that ?

(note: for the default mode, I tried expressing a rule ANYPATH defining a sequence of characters not starting by a HOSTNAME but failed)

Answer (score 0):

I recommend not to reinvent the wheel here. There is an [existing grammar for URLs](https://github.com/antlr/grammars-v4/tree/master/url), which should give you all the details you want.

**Update:**

In order to make the entire host/port part optional you could simply amend the url rule like this:

```
url
   : authority '://' login? host (':' port)? ('/' path)? ('?' search)?
   | '/'? path ('?' search)?
;
```

Did you try that already? I also see this grammar is not very flexible. Almost each part before the path part is optional (like the authority, the login info, port etc.).

Comment: Thanks. I have tried hacking this but I cannot get it to match URIs without hostnames (removing schemes requirements was not an issue).